# Set Helmet body class when element is active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I'm trying to create an image overlay with no scroll, and I therefore need to style the `body` when my `li` is active. I'm trying to do this through `Helmet`, but it's not working. It just says `<body class="">` in the browser—no matter if a `li` is active or not.

The component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

export default function ToggleActive({ children, size }) {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false")

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive)
  }

  return (
    <li className={isActive ? size : "active"} onClick={handleToggle}>
      <Helmet>
        <body className={isActive ? null : "no-scroll"} />
      </Helmet>
      {children}
      <button onClick={handleToggle} />
    </li>
  )
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: One thing wrong: !!"false" != false // true

Comment: OK, I guess it says `null` since the `body` isn't active. The question is how do I make it active when the `li` is active?

Comment: You are saying that you can find a case where li has the class "active" and body the null one ?

Comment: Yes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell me what happens when you get rid of the ternary operator and only keep 'active' and 'no-scroll' please ? Are they both in the state you want ?

Comment: Yes, they are. So Helmet is "working" fine when simply declaring a class.

Comment: I cannot help further. The only thing that bothers me is the fact that you are not using a boolean, from what I understand ii will not change much if you change "false" to false. But be carefull using this kind of syntax because a string like "false" is true. Also, from what i know it is better to do setActive(isActive => !isActive). Dont know why tho. Good luck have fun =)

Comment: Thanks. I don't get why this isn't working—it must be because of Helmet. Setting the state works for all other elements I've tried.

Comment: I found a "solution" using `useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("no-scroll", elementState)
  }, [elementState])`. But it causes the page to jump up to the top every time the `li` loses its active state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with Helmet.

Anyway, I found a solution:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

function ToggleActive({ children, size }) {
  const [elementState, setElementState] = useState(false)

  function handleClick() {
    setElementState(!elementState)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("no-scroll", elementState)
  }, [elementState])

  return (
    <li className={elementState ? "active" : size} onClick={handleClick}>
      {children}
      <button onClick={handleClick} />
    </li>
  )
}

export default ToggleActive
```